# I'm looking for manga or manhwa about girl that suffer dwarfism that make look like child and guy who is grown man but mind of a child

Tags: identification-request

I don't remember the manga well but is about a girl who suffered dwarfism and and guy whose full grown adult but mind of a child and it about their relationship and that all i remember

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Your identification requests is a bit sparse on details. For example, could you add in which language you read it and when? Could you review our [guidelines for identification requests](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and update the question? At the moment, it lacks details to enable people to answer it, so it will be closed until more details have been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this in reddit and it solved it "The Friendly Winter" by LEE Jun